# Why is there an error on running host program using git bash terminal?

Tags: bash, hostname, terminal

I am using git bash as a terminal to run code. I doing a course where it has asked us to use the host program to look up host names using DNS. However when I run nslookup it works fine.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWydx.png)

[running host command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX6kR.png)

Comment: In your screen shot it looks like you didn't actually run the host command, you just typed www.google.com as its own command.

Comment: Yes I have just realised. I had run the host command and it said `bash: host: command not found`. Question updated with screenshot

Comment: Git bash is not a complete Linux terminal environment. It only has a small subset of utilities available and `host` is not one of them.

Comment: Is there any way it can be installed or what other alternatives can I use running on a Windows 10 enterprise system?

Comment: [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) is the current solution for this. Cygwin is an older alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!